# How to set windows service startup type as Automatic (Delayed Start) during service creation?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have one windows service which I want to set start up type as "Automatic (Delayed start)" programatically so that during installation it should set as "Automatic (Delayed start)". I don't want to modify the registry. Without modifying registry information, I want to achieve this. Any suggestions?

Below is what I tried but no luck!

```
private static void SetStartModeToDelayedAuto(string serviceName)
{
    string command = string.Format("config {0} start= delayed-auto", serviceName);
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("SC", command);
    info.CreateNoWindow = true;
    info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    Process.Start(info);
}
```

Comment: Are you inherit the `Win32_Service`  class in your service? Please provide your service creation code as well.

Comment: Have a look at the [ServiceInstaller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller?view=netframework-4.8) class.